# Xamarin.Forms App created in Xamarin Studio on OS X gets broken by opening in VS 2015 Community

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin

If I create a new solution from the C# Forms App template in Xamarin Studio Community (latest stable updates) on OS X, then open that solution in Visual Studio 2015 Community (Update 3) on Windows 10 it adds loads of code to the Resource.designer.cs file. This will then build and run fine under VS but causes hundreds of build errors if I try to open that solution again under Xamarin on OS X.

The errors are "No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget. ... '"

Has anyone come across this before? Google didn't seem to give me anything that relates to this specifically.

Am I trying to do something that isn't supported? I assumed (possibly naively) that as iOS development on Windows isn't supported by Xamarin (it recommends I use VS) I would be able to switch between IDEs based on my OS. VS under Windows is happily talking to my Mac for debugging etc, just a shame I can't seem to share the solution without reverting a ton of changes each time.

Comment: You are not sync'ing any of the generated designer files or the `obj` (or bin, packages, etc..) directory are you? I sync (via git) solution/projects between Win/VS and OSX/XS (& Android Studio) all the time and as long as I do not include any of those I do not have any problems (and of course using the same Xamarin versions across those platforms)

Comment: Very good point @SushiHangover, I'll check, I just used whatever default .gitignore that Xamarin Studio added when I told it to use git.

Comment: "In Theory" it should just work... the same msbuild/xbuild `.targets` are being used on both platforms, so assuming the underlaying "tools" are the same (Xamarin.Android|iOS versions, Android SDK tools, build-tools, platform-tools, etc... ) the same build artifacts (dll/ipa/apk/..) should be generated... There have been known older issues of `.storyboard` and `.xib`'s being editing via the VS/Xamarin add-in causing problems on OS-X but I do not know if any of those issues are still outstanding...

Comment: Ah, thanks, that's exactly what it was; that Resources.designer.cs file needed to be added to my .gitignore and it all plays well now.

Comment: Great to hear it, happy xammie coding...